# Bitcoin and Bitcoincash

Tags: bitcoin-cash, sending

A weird thing happened on my account and I would appreciate your help.
Today I logged in, and BCH appeared on my account - I wasn't buying any lately and when I click on history of transactions in BCH section, there is no track of received BCH as well. 
Yesterday I had no BCH.
Could anybody explain it to me?

Another question: When I want to send my BTC and I enter the address and the amount, the SEND button does not work.
Anybody knows why?

Comment: Which software or website are you talking about?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome browser and as wallet I use Blockchain.

Comment: This is not a support forum for a particular service. You should ask there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user is seeking support for a third-party service. The question is not related to Bitcoin per se.

Comment: I'm voting to keep this open: https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/871/usage-of-the-off-topic-reason-customer-relationship

Answer (score 1):

Probably you had some BTC on address balance during the fork of BCH, so you get this balance by snapshot